# Emacs eshell - Kill window on exit

Tags: emacs, eshell

I have the following code in my `init.el`

```
;;open eshell
(defun eshell-other-window ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((buf (eshell)))
    (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer buf))
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window buf)
  )
)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-t") 'eshell-other-window)
```

This works fine until I exit eshell. When I exit, the window stays open. How do I get the window to close automatically?

Comment: How about using the function `delete-window`, which has an optional argument to specify a particular window if so desired?  [See also `delete-other-windows`.]  You can also use things like `select-window` to select a particular window, and you can use things like `set-window-buffer` to display a buffer in a particular window.  And, you can get a window object with a function such as `selected-window` and/or `window-in-direction` with the arguments `'above`, `'below`, `'left`, `'right`.

Comment: @lawlist yes, but how would I do that on eshell exit

Comment: `kill-buffer` and `delete-window`, but check to see if more than one window exists.

Comment: i understand i need to use those commands, but how do i execute when I run the `exit` command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following answer assumes that the user is typing `exit` at the command prompt in the `*Eshell*` buffer followed by the return/enter key, and the answer assumes that the function `eshell/exit` is doing its thing.  [The user is still free to customize the variable `eshell-kill-on-exit` to either burry or kill the `*Eshell*` buffer when exiting.]

```lisp
(require 'eshell)

(defun my-custom-func () 
  (when (not (one-window-p))
    (delete-window)))

(advice-add 'eshell-life-is-too-much :after 'my-custom-func)
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [what @lawlist wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51867960/1613005) back in 2018, and as i could not make it work using `use-package`, this is the solution I ended up using:

```lisp
(use-package eshell
  :ensure nil
  :init
  (defun mm/kill-window-if-no-last ()
    "Checks if this window is NOT the last window, it will kill this window"
    (when (not (one-window-p))
      (delete-window)))

  :hook (
         (eshell-exit . mm/kill-window-if-no-last)
         )
  )
```

Please note that my `mm/kill-window-if-no-last` function is practically the `my-custom-func` in [the @lawlist answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51867960/1613005), just with a more descriptive name and also some description.